# Percentage height within auto height parent div?

Tags: html, css, height

How do you get a child div to be 120% the height of a parent, when the parent height is unspecified (auto)?

When the parent has a specified height it works:

```css
#bar {
  background-color:rgba(120,0,0,0.5);
  height:120px;
}

#child {
  background-color:rgba(0,120,0,0.5);
  height:120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div id="child">
    Lorem<br/>
    ipsum<br/>
    dolor<br/>
    sit<br/>
    amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

When the parent height is auto (unspecified) it fails:

```css
#bar {
  background-color:rgba(120,0,0,0.5);
}

#child {
  background-color:rgba(0,120,0,0.5);
  height:120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div id="child">
    Lorem<br/>
    ipsum<br/>
    dolor<br/>
    sit<br/>
    amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:before` instead on a child div.

```css
#bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color:rgba(120,0,0,0.5);
}

#bar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color:rgba(0,120,0,0.5);

}

#child {
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <div id="child">
    Lorem<br/>
    ipsum<br/>
    dolor<br/>
    sit<br/>
    amet.
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad, but this still means that whatever element inside of bar will not have the desired height.

Comment: The height of `#bar` depends on it's parent div since you are not giving it a fixed height

Comment: You can put as many elements as you want inside of `#bar`, and the height will stretch each time you add an element, and at the same time, the `:after` element will also increase height. What is  your desired height ??

Comment: The problem is not a certain desired height (the element is dynamically growing and shrinking in height). The challenge actually is that #bar has a certain background while #child has a certain semi-transparent svg background which must be 120% higher.

This is why the size you calculate is correct but I cannot give a background to #bar and #bar:after together right?

Comment: Please check my updated Answer. I am using now `:before`, and setting it to the top of the div with a height of 120%. I guess this is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Well done until here, thanks. Now the only difference to my fixed height example is that the font "Lorem ipsum ..." is behind the before element, any idea how to bring the text only back to the front?

Comment: Give me some time to figure out a solution

Comment: Sure this is also not exactly what I want because I mean only inner elements of #bar should go to the front but i will figure out myself if you want, you have given the right direction.

Comment: Edited now its perfect.

Comment: Great Solution!

Answer (score 5):

Logically this will not work because the height of your `height: auto` element is determined by the height of its children. If the height of the child relied on the automatic height of the parent you'd end up with a circular dependency. Because of this problem, children of auto-height elements cannot have their height rely on that element - percentage units will therefore be ignored.

You'll need to take a step back and come up with a different approach to whatever it is you're ultimately trying to achieve.